# How do I get ProgressBar tint colour to work on API 21?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-api-levels

I've set progress bar tint in XML, but it isn't working on API 21 (Android 5.0)

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:progressTint="@color/blue"/>
```

The tint is the default yellow colour on API 21, but is correctly blue on API 22 and above.

According to the docs, the corresponding set method `setProgressTintList` was introduced in API 21, so I don't understand why this doesn't work. (My minimum API version is 21 so I don't need to worry about lower versions.)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `xml` like this (Work on API 21+):

```
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:progressTint="@color/blue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/blue">
```

and with Java:

```
Drawable progressDrawable = yourProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().mutate();
progressDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, 
android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
yourProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
```

and for you case **API 21** seting a progress tint with java should also work:

```
yourProgressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

or

```
yourProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: But I'm not trying to create an indeterminate progress bar, I'm trying to create a determinate one...and I'm also trying to do this in XML